# What are the restrictions of exporting a virtual class from a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, dll, virtual

I'm using gcc and msvc.  My goal is to make a dynamic library framework as a collection of some basic functionality seen across multiple programs.  Using a virtual class seemed intuitive to me for making default behavior to execute on most programs, using virtual functions that can be overridden by other programs that differ slightly.

The main ideal I'm looking for in a dynamic library is that new exported symbols can be added to the library without rebuilding all of the dependent binaries.  Also, adding internal functionality should be simple.  My main concern is linking requirements.  What are some of the requirements for exporting a virtual class, or pure virtual, from a dynamic library so that another binary can be compiled and linked with a child class? Specifically:

1. When does the entire base class need to be exported? i.e. using **declspec(dllexport/dllimport) or __attribute**((visibility("default"))) in the class declaration.
2. When can the export attribute be omitted from the class declaration, and only be placed in front of the desired methods?
3. Do all methods declared virtual in the base class need to be exported?
4. How are the symbols added to the base class by the compiler exported? (virtual table address and typeinfo)
5. Can the symbols added to the base class by the compiler be explicitly exported without exporting the entire class?
6. In MSVC, when the entire class is exported can individual methods or members be "unexported"?  i.e similar to using the **attribute**((visibility("hidden"))) or #pragma GCC visibility push(default) on individual methods / members.
7. Do any of the requirements differ depending on whether the base class is regular, virtual, or pure virtual?

Run time related

8.. Is it safe to declare a dynamic class, or a child of a dynamic class on the stack or should they always be allocated on the heap using new/delete?